# MySQLWorkbench returns 'OK' instead of returning rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

ok so, im trying to generate "TOP 5 name of childcare centres that is popular among the SC and SPR" and i got an "OK" instead of "xxx rows returned" in mySQLWorkbench output. Issit possible for anyone of you to check if my query is correct??

mySQLWorkbench version is 8.0.18

```
SELECT centre_service.centre_name
FROM centre_service
WHERE centre_service.centre_code = centre.centre_code  AND (type_of_citizenship = "SC" OR type_of_citizenship = "SPR") AND centre_name = (
SELECT centre.centre_name
FROM centre
GROUP BY centre_name LIMIT 5
);
```

Comment: `centre` is not defined so the query is not even "OK".

Comment: what do u mean by "centre is not even defined"?

Comment: . . More specifically `centre.centre_code` in the `WHERE` clause is not defined.

Comment: In other words, you can't reference columns of `centre` in the outer query. You should get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'centre.centre_code' in 'where clause' 
`

Comment: Another problem: comparing `centre_name = (...subquery...)` when the subquery is not a scalar subquery. If you use `=` then you must ensure the subquery returns only one row. So this whole query is invalid for multiple reasons, there's no way it can execute successfully.

Answer (score 5):

This answer does not tackle the errors in the query, but helps to answer the question about why neither an error is seen nor data rows, and what can be done about it.

MySQL Workbench does not handle all types of query errors nicely. Sometimes it just returns "OK" with no rows. I have seen this with, for example, illegal mixed collation errors.

When this happens, just issue this in the query tab:

```
show errors;
```

This will return one or more errors, each with a level, a code and a message. For example, my query (details not important) returned "OK" and nothing else. Then `show errors` gave me this:

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | 1267 | Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' |

I cannot say for certain, but it seems like [some?] run-time errors are prone to this problem, rather than syntax errors that are caught immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. You had 2 mistakes: using reference of a table from subquery in an outer scope (replaced to the inner scope) and using comparison operator to the multiple values (changed to `IN`).

```
SELECT centre_service.centre_name
FROM centre_service 
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT centre_name
      FROM centre
      GROUP BY centre_name LIMIT 5
   ) centre ON centre.centre_name = centre_service.centre_name
WHERE 
   (type_of_citizenship = "SC" OR type_of_citizenship = "SPR") AND
   centre_service.centre_code = centre.centre_code;
```

Comment: hi there, thank you so much for the entry. But i got an Error code 1235 that states "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support "LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"..

Comment: Please edit your question and specify your MYSQL version.

Comment: sorry, im very new to stack overflow.. how do i edit my question?

Comment: You have link `edit` below tags of your question. Anyway I modified my answer, because previous was incorrect. I think it's equivalent to yours.

Comment: i see, found it, thankyou. I'm using version 8.0.18..

Comment: No, instead of returning top 5, it returns all the column from centre_service column

Comment: You must add `LIMIT 5` to the query then, at the end. I will not edit answer because I'm not sure what output you want to get finally. Check this topic and try to provide MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example